# Rebasing with git a branch that contains a merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Here is a git tree

[image]

My goal is to rebase the commits `branch_1` over `master` so `C`, `E`, `F` and `G` are added on master after D as in the following diagram

[image]

I've setup a public github repo that reproduce the situtation before the rebase on https://github.com/gissehel-sandbox-org/sandbox-git-rebase-on-merge

The README.md page on the repo explains more in detail how the test cases are created if this explanation is not enought.

There is a *testcase1* where commit `E` and commit `F` don't conflict, *but* merge `G` add a line. (which is not a best practice, but it's to show that the problem in the second test case lie here).

There is a *testcase2* where commit `E` and commit `F` conflicts, and merge `G` solve the commit by something else that commit `E` and commit `F` (common merge with conflict use case).

However I do the rebase, the change in commit `G` are always ignored (in both use cases).

My question is, is there a way to safely rebase a branch that contains a merge without having to redo the entier merge (which may be unsafe when the merge is complex) ?

Example rebase

```
git checkout testcase2/branch1
git rebase testcase2/master
```

Here the commit `F` raise the same conflict as the ones already solved in merge `G`, and the merge `G` is ignored.

Another example:

```
git checkout testcase2/branch1
git rebase testcase2/master --rebase-merges
```

Here the topology of the branch is kept, *but style not the content of the merge `G`*, the conflict has to be solved again.

I understand that people have strong opinions about whether using rebase or not, and I am fully conscient that those two options would not had problems:

- having used rebase for `branch_2` over `branch_1` and then `branch_1` over `master`
- having merged `branch_2` into `branch_1` and the merged `branch_1` into `master`

The question is not about it's a good idea to be in that situation, the question is really about when the code is that state, and I want (whether you think it's a good idea or not) to make a rebase, is git able to safely rebase or not (using some options I don't know for example) ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid recreating the merge somehow, and if there were merge conflicts before, there will be merge conflicts again. So you'll just have to accept that part.

Also, there's a lot more going on here than just a rebase: your second diagram throws the merge away and just puts `F'` inline after `E'`, rather than growing out of `C'` the way F grows out of C. So there is going to be *no* "merge" in your second diagram (and so I don't see what `G'` is supposed to be for).

What I would do is:

1. Copy the entire working tree folder to somewhere else just in case.
2. Rebase just the part before the merge:

   ```
    git switch --det E
    git switch -c temp
    git rebase --onto D B temp
   ```
3. This will give you `C'` and `E'` in the right place. So far so good! Now cherry-pick F:

   ```
    git cherry-pick F
   ```
4. That's a merge, and there may be merge conflicts. Deal with them. Now cherry-pick G (but see my note below):

   ```
    git cherry-pick -m1 G
   ```
5. Finally, fix the branch names:

   ```
    git branch -M branch_1
   ```

**NOTE** But I don't quite see what step 4 is for, or why you think you need G to be part of the result at all. It's just a merge commit, and the cherry-pick of F, which is going to "flatten" this whole thing, *is* that merge commit in effect. So I'm suggesting your original diagram of your goal is just wrong, and that all you need, in order to get the flattened rebase you are after, is everything thru `F'` and no `G'` at all.

Comment: about your note: I had that same thought, and then re-read the OP's question: the OP clearly mentions situations where `G` brings in extra changes -- fixes a conflict or introduces extra changes

Comment: In all my use cases, G brings some changes that neither E nor F brings (which often occurs with complex merges...)
That's why I provided an actual github repo as example.
My "target" graph does conaints C' E' F' G' as linear, but it can keep the topology.

What I want is "some way" to take into account G to merge the conflicts between E' and F' (even if that requires a special manual step)

Comment: @gissehel If your question had asked to keep the original topology (the triangle as F emerges from C and then merges back in as G) I would have told you how to achieve that; in fact, when I originally wrote my answer, I gave instructions for that. Then I noticed that you also wanted the new branch flattened, throwing away the extra branch containing F. So that is what I described.